# how to deserialize a JSON to an Entity using setters

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I'm writing a `Controller` that accept a JSON representing a user I have to create. I'm trying to keep the controller it as light as possible and for that reason I let `FOSRestBundle` deserializing the JSON into the proper Entity I want to save:

```
   /**
     * @View()
     *
     * @ApiDoc(
     *  description="It creates a new user",
     *  section="Users"
     * )
     *
     * @Post("/users")
     * @ParamConverter("user", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
     */
    public function postAction(User $user)
    {
        $res = $this->getHandler()->create($user);
        ...
```

and yes, everything works smoothly! Except for a *caviat*: I would like to encrypt the password, and `User`'s entity does it in its `setPassword` method. Is there a way to do it automatically? Or should I call `User::setPassword` by myself in the handler I wrote?

Comment: what about using a virtualProperty where you can do your stuff? Otherwise you need to subscribe on a serialization event and do more stuff with other service involved

Comment: I've just realized how to do that: a service-listener  that listens to Doctrine's `prePersist` event. That way, I can re-set the password

Comment: add your solution as an own answer so people don't try to answer you and to help others getting the same problem